# Flutter get all images from website with given URL

Tags: flutter, image, dart, webview

I am trying to scrape **any** website for its images and save them in a list. For that I am using the `getElementsByTagname("img")` and also selected the `['src']` attributes like this:

```
  void _getData() async {
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(_currentUrl));
    final host = Uri.parse(_currentUrl).host;
    dom.Document document = parser.parse(response.body);
    final elements = document.getElementsByTagName("img").toList();
    for (var element in elements) {
      var imageSource = element.attributes['src'] ?? '';
      print(imageSource);
      bool validURL = Uri.parse(imageSource).host == '' ||
              Uri.parse(host + imageSource).host == ''
          ? false
          : true;

      if (validURL && !imageSource.endsWith('svg')) {
        Uri imageSourceUrl = Uri.parse(imageSource);
        if (imageSourceUrl.host.isEmpty) {
          imageSource = host + imageSource;
        }

        if (_imagesWithSize.firstWhereOrNull(
              (element) => element.imageUrl == imageSource,
            ) ==
            null) {
          Size size = await _calculateImageDimension(imageSource);
          _imagesWithSize.add(
            ImageWithSize(
              imageSource,
              size,
            ),
          );
        }
      }
    }
    _imagesWithSize.sort(
      (a, b) => (b.imageSize.height * b.imageSize.width).compareTo(
        a.imageSize.height * a.imageSize.width,
      ),
    );
  }
```

**Problem:**

This does not work with this link:

[HM Productlink](https://www2.hm.com/de_de/productpage.1082211003.html)

I get this URL:

```
//lp2.hm.com/hmgoepprod?set=quality%5B79%5D%2Csource%5B%2F0c%2Fe6%2F0ce67f87aa6691557f30371590cf854ed0fb77c7.jpg%5D%2Corigin%5Bdam%5D%2Ccategory%5B%5D%2Ctype%5BLOOKBOOK%5D%2Cres%5Bm%5D%2Chmver%5B1%5D&call=url[file:/product/main]
```

And this is not a valid URL...

How can I parse the image from this website?

Let me know if you need any more info!

Answer (score 0):

Links with leading double slashes are valid in HTML, as part of [RFC1808](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1808). They will be replaced by `http` or `https` depending on the context. It will probably work if you add the scheme (`http:` or `https:`) from `_currentUrl` to `imageSourceUrl`.

I have not tested this, but I assume something like this would work:

```dart
if (!imageSourceUrl.hasScheme) {
  final scheme = Uri.parse(_currentUrl).scheme;
  imageSourceUrl = imageSourceUrl.replace(scheme: scheme);
}
```